# System.AccessViolationException while setting DataContext in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I navigate to a new page and on that page I set the `DataContext` on the page load event.

```
public MyPage()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  this.Loaded += MyPage_Loaded;

} 
void MyPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.DataContext= myModel;

}
```

While setting the data context, lot of times I get `System.AccessViolation` exception and the application quits.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT**

I tried following

1) set `NavigationCacheMode` to `Disabled`

2) Made the page to basic page i.e. remove inheriting from `LayoutAwarePage`

I am still getting that exception

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown? Right at `this.DataContext=...`? Are you referencing something in `myModel` with a binding that is possibly causing the exception?

Comment: @NateDiamond The exception is thrown at this statement `this.DataContext= myModel;`

Comment: @NateDiamond didn't understood your second question

Comment: So the DataContext property allows you to do DataBindings via the properties of the DataContext. The question is, is one of those properties when it is being accessed causing the AccessViolation, either through something like running something Async or doing some file IO.

Comment: @NateDiamond there's no async or file I/O happening inside the properties. `myModel` has simple properties which have data prior setting the datacontext

Comment: your code looks fine, you may like to post the myModel code for further investigation

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that data which the UI binds to is only changed by the UI thread. You can something like

```
    public static async Task RunOnUIThread(DispatchedHandler action)
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
    }
```